# Помогите разобраться с подключением slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, slick.js

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <h1>Hello My Friend</h1>
        <a href="">1123456789</a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <h1>Hello My Friend</h1>
        <a href="">1123456789</a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <h1>Hello My Friend</h1>
        <a href="">1123456789</a>
    </div>
</div>    


;

"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true
 })
});



let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
let autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
let concat = require('gulp-concat');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('css', function() {
return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
return gulp.src([
    './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    './node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    './slick/slick.min.js',
    './src/js/index.js',
])
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', ['css']);
 gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js']);
```

Постоянная ошибка - `$(...).slick is not a function.`

Помогите понять почему эта ошибка.

Comment: тут 3 файла в одном, html, js, gulp. Весь прикол в том, что бутстрап работает, а slick - нет

Comment: Попробуйте `stream-series` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388763/1430631 или `gulp-add-src` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31187270/1430631

Answer (score 0):

Перемести свой код в самый низ если это написано в одном файле, потому что ты сначало пытаешься использовать библиотеку,а потом ее подключаешь.

Comment: это 3 разных файла в одном здесь : html, js, gulp

Comment: @max мб версия jquery не та ? попробуй подключить все js в html вручную